# Power of trigonometric function matrix

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, complex, trigonometry

Calculate the m-power of the following trigonometric function matrix (m>0):

$\boldsymbol{A}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi \\ \sin \varphi & \cos \varphi\end{array}\right)$

The answer in the textbook is:

$\boldsymbol{A}^{m}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos m \varphi & -\sin m \varphi \\ \sin m \varphi & \cos m \varphi\end{array}\right)$

But the result I get with MMA code contains complex numbers. How can I get the same answer as the textbook?

```
Clear["Global`*"];
A = {{Cos[\[CurlyPhi]], -Sin[\[CurlyPhi]]}, {Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], 
    Cos[\[CurlyPhi]]}};
MatrixPower[A, m]
```

> $\left\{\left\{\frac{1}{2}(\operatorname{Cos}[\varphi]-i \operatorname{Sin}[\varphi])^{\mathrm{m}}+\frac{1}{2}(\operatorname{Cos}[\varphi]+i \operatorname{Sin}[\varphi])^{\mathrm{m}},-\frac{1}{2} i(\operatorname{Cos}[\varphi]-i \sin [\varphi])^{\mathrm{m}}+\frac{1}{2} i(\operatorname{Cos}[\varphi]+i \operatorname{Sin}[\varphi])^{\mathrm{m}}\right\},\right.$,
> $\left.\left\{\frac{1}{2} i(\operatorname{Cos}[\varphi]-i \operatorname{Sin}[\varphi])^{\mathrm{m}}-\frac{1}{2} i(\operatorname{Cos}[\varphi]+i \operatorname{Sin}[\varphi])^{\mathrm{m}}, \frac{1}{2}(\operatorname{Cos}[\varphi]-i \sin [\varphi])^{\mathrm{m}}+\frac{1}{2}(\operatorname{Cos}[\varphi]+i \operatorname{Sin}[\varphi])^{\mathrm{m}}\right\}\right\}$

Comment: Try `Assuming[φ ∈ Reals && m ∈ Integers && m > 0, FullSimplify[TrigToExp[MatrixPower[RotationMatrix[φ], m]]]]` and report back.

Comment: Thank you！@J. M.'s persistent exhaustion ♦